# Encrypt with DES in Node.js, decrypt in VB.net

Tags: node.js, vb.net, encryption, cryptography

I've got some legacy Visual Basic code that uses DES for encryption. Right now, a file is encrypted and decrypted in Visual Basic. As a first step in replacing the code, I would like to move the encryption to Node.js while avoiding changing the Visual Basic decryption code for the time-being. This boils down to encrypting with DES in Node.js in such a way that it can be  decrypted using the current Visual Basic implementation.

The problem is that the implementation of DES in Microsoft's DESCryptoServiceProvider class is pretty opaque. I've been able to figure out that CBC (cipher block chaining) is used for the mode, that the padding is PKCS7, and that there is no salt being applied to the key, but there are missing details, like the iterations applied to the key.

Here is how a file is currently encrypted (ie. what I would like to implement in Node.js):

```
Sub EncryptFile(ByVal sInputFilename As String, _
               ByVal sOutputFilename As String, _
               ByVal sKey As String)

        Dim fsInput As New FileStream(sInputFilename, _
                                    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim fsEncrypted As New FileStream(sOutputFilename, _
                                    FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)

        Dim DES As New DESCryptoServiceProvider()

        'Set secret key for DES algorithm.
        'A 64-bit key and an IV are required for this provider.
        DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey)

        'Set the initialization vector.
        DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey)

        'Create the DES encryptor from this instance.
        Dim desencrypt As ICryptoTransform = DES.CreateEncryptor()

        'Create the crypto stream that transforms the file stream by using DES encryption.
        Dim cryptostream As New CryptoStream(fsEncrypted, _
                                            desencrypt, _
                                            CryptoStreamMode.Write)

        'Read the file text to the byte array.
        Dim bytearrayinput(CInt(fsInput.Length - 1)) As Byte

        fsInput.Read(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length)

        'Write out the DES encrypted file.
        cryptostream.Write(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length)
        cryptostream.Close()

        fsInput.Close()
End Sub
```

It basically uses default values for most of the parameters and properties of DESCryptoServiceProvider.

And here is how the resulting file is decrypted in Visual Basic:

```
        Dim DES As New DESCryptoServiceProvider()

        'Set the secret key for the DES algorithm.
        DES.Key() = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("12345678")
        'Set the initialization vector.
        DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("12345678")

        Dim fsread As New FileStream(FileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

        Dim desdecrypt As ICryptoTransform = DES.CreateDecryptor()

        Dim cryptostreamDecr As New CryptoStream(fsread, desdecrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Read)

        Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(cryptostreamDecr)

        'We can now read unencrypted text from sr
```

The crux of the problem is surmising enough of the details of Microsoft's DES implementation to reproduce the encryption side of things in another language. Heck, I'd be over the moon if I could use OpenSSL to DES-encrypt something that could be decrypted by a DESCryptoServiceProvider in Visual Basic. That could be built upon.

Here is what I've come up with in Node.js:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs');

let key = new Buffer('12345678', 'ascii')
let iv = new Buffer('12345678', 'ascii');

try {
    const data = fs.readFileSync('blah.txt', { encoding: 'binary' });
    console.log(data);

    let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-cbc', key, iv);

    let c = cipher.update(data, 'binary', 'binary');
    
    c += cipher.final('binary');

    fs.writeFileSync('blah.des', c)
}
catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
}
```

The output doesn't match what is produced by the Visual Basic encryption. Trying to decrypt the Node.js (above) encrypted file with the Visual Basic decryption (above) throws an error of "Length of the data to decrypt is invalid".

Comment: A DES key has 64bit including parity or 56bit without parity. Thus `ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Blah")` is never a valid DES key.

Comment: The VB code implements a plain encryption/decryption with DES using the default mode and padding, namely CBC and PKCS#7. Key and IV are passed directly, i.e. no key derivation is performed, so there is no salt or iteration count. Post your NodeJS code, please.

Comment: Robert's comment is true. I replaced the key and IV with dummy text when sanitizing it for use in this question. I've changed it to something valid to avoid confusing anyone who reads it in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the posted NodeJS code, the ciphertext `c` is a latin1/binary decoded string, which is written to a file with [`fs.writeFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fswritefilesyncfile-data-options) without specifying the encoding in the 3rd parameter. This applies the default encoding, namely UTF-8, which leads to the corruption of the ciphertext. Correct is:

```js
fs.writeFileSync('blah.des', c, { encoding: 'binary' })
```

With this change, the NodeJS code returns the same ciphertext as the VB code.

---

The current NodeJS code reads the data from the file and performs a latin1/binary decoding into a string. This string is latin1/binary encoded on encryption and the resulting ciphertext is latin1/binary decoded. When writing to the file a latin1/binary encoding is performed (assuming the above fix was implemented).

It is more efficient to avoid the encodings/decodings and to process the data in binary form, i.e. read the data from the file into a buffer, encrypt the data contained in the buffer, store the ciphertext in a buffer, and write the ciphertext from the buffer into the file:

```js
try {
    const data = fs.readFileSync('blah.txt');
    console.log(data);

    let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-cbc', key, iv);
    let c = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(data), cipher.final()]);

    fs.writeFileSync('blah.des', c)
}
catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
}
```

This implementation also returns the same ciphertext as the VB code.

Comment: Confirmed. The default encoding of writeFileSync() was the issue. With binary encoding specified, or implied by reading the file as binary data, all is well. Thanks @Topaco!